Vless + Reality/TLS keeps timing out every 10-20 minutes
Tried all sorts of trickery and still consistently get these types of messages:
ERROR[2191] [1626364148 22m42s] inbound/mixed[mixed-in]: process connection from 127.0.0.1:59576: download: read tcp [my ip address]:59320->[server's ip address]:443: read: connection timed out

Also, with Tun mode on I get errors like this:
ERROR[0752] [118890752 12m21s] inbound/tun[tun-in]: download: read tcp [my ip address]:56006->[server's ip address]:443: read: connection timed out

With Tun mode on I get:
ERROR[0463] [1919113431 10.0s] dns: exchange failed for gateway.discord.gg. IN A: context deadline exceeded

Tried changing ServerAliveInterval and ClientAliveInterval on client and server sides respectively, changing remote DNS in nekoray, turning on FakeDNS
